# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in

Tags: php

i have this error i'm working to insert image to db but i m getting this error
my code here

```
$sql="INSERT INTO uygulama 
            (no,baslik,aciklama,resimler,
            tur,kategori,yapimci,boyut,
            indirmelinki,APK,tarih) 
        VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, "'.$db.'", ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);  
if ($stmt === false) die ("sorgu hatası".$db->error);

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", 
                $_POST['baslik'], $_POST['aciklama'], $_POST['resimler'], 
                $_POST['tur'], $_POST['kategori'], $_POST['yapimci'], 
                $_POST['boyut'], $_POST['indirmelinki'], $_POST['APK']);

$stmt->execute();
if (!$stmt) {
   die('Kayıt eklenmedi');
} else{
    echo "Başarıyla Kaydedildi";
}

}

echo "</div>";


## Uzantı Kontrollerim
$uzanti=    array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png','image/x-png','image/gif');
## Aynı Dizinde Bulunan Resimler Klasörüne Kaydet
$dizin=     "app_images";
if(in_array(strtolower($_FILES['resimler']['type']),$uzanti)){ 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resimler']['tmp_name'],"./$dizin/{$_FILES['resimler']['name']}");
    ## Türkçe Karakter Hatası
    $db = $_FILES['resimler']['name'];    
}

        <tr>
            <td>Resimler:</td>
            <td>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" >
                    <input type="file" name="resimler" multiple="multiple" value=""/>
                </form><br/>
                <div id="goster"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>';
```

Comment: `'.$db.'` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Please type your error message so that we can read it!

Comment: i typed already in title

Comment: how can add $db into insert

Comment: WEll now you have an answer. If you write your code in a sensibly indented and orderly way. Errors like this are **blatently obvious** rather than being hidden amongst a cloud of code

Comment: `$db` is your mysqli connection object. You cannot want that store that in your database. **Have you reused a variable name by any chance**

Comment: i changed the name as $resimler now i have tihs error sorgu hatasıColumn count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: DUH, well count the `?` and then count the variables you are passing to fill the `?` placeholders

Answer (score 2):

Why are you stuffing you DB object into your query string?

```
$sql = " .... ?, "'.$db.'", ?,...";
                   ^^^^
```

next time, try to actually **READ** the error message, and go look at the line of code it indicates where the error occurs. PHP doesn't spit out errors because it's having a bad hair day. It spits out errors because YOU committed an error.